# Making link from another link

Tags: jquery, html

I have been using X-Editable with jquery-ui and I am trying to add be able when I click on the "Add Another Select2" link I want to add another select2 items. With this code I am able to add the item but it is not functional (combo box aka select2 doesn't show on the new link and on the old one is working). [Here is a demo of the X-Editable plugin](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) where I am using "Select2 (dropdown mode)"

```
<a href="#" class="schools" data-type="select2" 
   data-pk="1" data-value="1" data-title="Choose item"></a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="add-school">Add Another Select</a>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click', '.add-school', function() {
        var o = $(".schools").first();
        o.clone().insertAfter(o);
    });

    $('.schools').editable({
        value: 2,
        source: [
            {id: 1, text: 'Item 1'},
            {id: 2, text: 'Item 2'},
            {id: 3, text: 'Item 3'}
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas how this might work?

Comment: I did not understand this part :  (combo box aka select2 doesn't show on the new link and on the old one is working)

Comment: combobox aka select2 from X-Editable